# i'm trying to make a password generater gui app using python and kivy but it doesn't work

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

hi i'm trying to make an app that generates a password when clicking the button "generate" using python (for the logic) and kivy(for the gui) and i think that i did everything right but when i click the genrate button ,the app stops for a bit and then return working but the text content which was originaly empty doesn't change into a random password,the box just remains empty.
so guys plz help me.the python code is here:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import requests
import random
class float_layout(Widget):
     passw= ObjectProperty(None)
     btn = ObjectProperty(None)
     password = StringProperty("")
     def change(self,password):
      word_site = "https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000"
      signs = ["__","_","**",":","::",";",";;","&","&&","***","-","--","---","***","&&&"]
      sign = random.choice(signs)

      response = requests.get(word_site)
      WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
      number = random.randint(0,len(WORDS))
      addition1 = random.randint(0,100000)
      word= WORDS[number].decode('utf-8')+sign+str(addition1)
      word = StringProperty(word)
      
      return password == word
     
              
class GenApp(App):
     def build(self):
         return float_layout()
         
if __name__=="__main__":
     GenApp().run()
```

here is the kivy code:

```
#:kivy 1.0
<float_layout>
   passw:passw
   btn:btn
   FloatLayout:
      size: root.width,root.height
      
      TextInput:
         id:passw
         text:root.password
         size_hint:0.5,0.1
         pos_hint:{"x":0.25,"top":0.5}
         multiline:False
      Button:
         id:btn
         text:"Generate"
         size_hint:0.5,0.1
         pos_hint:{"x":0.25,"top":0.41}
         background_color:0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1
         on_press:root.change(root.password)
            
      Image:
         source: r'C:\Users\Med\Desktop\photoshop\password_gen.png'
         pos_hint:{"x":0,"top":1.2}
```

here is an image of the app:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkh22.png

Comment: OMG, you need to work on your code structure. Your kv script is good but work on your Python code. Class name should start with capital letter. Separations of Concerns (backend vs frontend. Assigning vs callback vs verification.) More descriptive variable names.

Comment: sorry man but i made the app just for practice so i didn't care much for the names but i should take your advice

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

```
return password == word
```

with:

```
self.password = word
# return password == word
```

The `return password == word` will return either `True` or `False` depending on whether `word` is the same as the `root.password`. And the return value is not used anyway.

The `text` of the `TextInput` is already set to use whatever is in `root.password`, so you can just set that property.

Also, there is no need to pass in the current password value.

Comment: thanks man you truly made my day i'm always grateful for your help